# Does codename one cloud bind to other cloud storage services?

Tags: codenameone

Can we bind codename one apps to cloud storage services other than those provided by codenameone?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. E.g. dropbox support https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-codenameone-sdk/

Comment: What of services like Parse?

Comment: I'm not sure which such services exist really. I was answering the theoretical question. There is also support for salesforce and other such tools but I'm not aware of any project similar to parse with any degree of traction.